# Pre-multiplied alpha compositing in GLSL shader leaves very transparent area

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I've put together a shader for a rounded rectangle with a drop shadow (there are lots of examples online, but none that exactly meet my needs). I used a derivation of the SDF formula from here https://iquilezles.org/articles/distfunctions/ to draw the rounded rectangle, `smoothstep` to blur the shadow, and the anti-aliasing formula from here https://mortoray.com/antialiasing-with-a-signed-distance-field/.

I can display the anti-aliased rectangle on its own, but when I attempt to blend it over the drop shadow with an end target of pre-multiplied alpha (if it matters, a Vulkan swapchain image with `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_PRE_MULTIPLIED_BIT_KHR`), the pixels on the corners of the rectangle appear to be showing through all the way to the background--i.e. the drop shadow is not visible behind them. It's as if the rounded rectangle is fully clipped from the shadow.

I believe this is due to my misunderstanding of alpha compositing and the formula I've taken from the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing. However, I can't reason through fixing it.

Please the the screenshot showing the issue:

[image: screenshot of rounded rectangle and dropshadow]

[image: closeup of corner]

And here is the GLSL fragment shader:

```c
#version 450

layout(location=0) out vec4 outColor;

float sdfRoundedRectangle(vec2 p, vec2 b, float r) {
    vec2 q = abs(p) - b + r;
    return min(max(q.x, q.y), 0.0) + length(max(q, 0.0)) - r;
}

vec2 extent = vec2(600.0, 400.0);
float cornerRadius = 10.0;
float blurRadius = 20.0;
vec3 fragColor = vec3(0.2, 0.5, 0.5);
vec3 shadowPaint = vec3(0.0);

void main()
{
    vec2 center = extent.xy / 2.0;
    vec2 size = (extent.xy / 2.0) - blurRadius;

    float boxDistance = sdfRoundedRectangle(gl_FragCoord.xy - center, size, cornerRadius);

    float boxAlpha = clamp(0.5 - boxDistance, 0.0, 1.0);
    float shadowAlpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(-blurRadius, blurRadius, boxDistance);

    float outAlpha = boxAlpha + (shadowAlpha * (1.0 - boxAlpha));
    vec3 outRgb = ((fragColor * boxAlpha) + (shadowPaint * shadowAlpha * (1.0 - boxAlpha))) / outAlpha;
    outColor = vec4(outRgb * outAlpha, outAlpha);
}
```

**Update:**

Simply adding the alpha values of the rectangle and shadow (rather than adding the product of the shadow alpha multiplied by the inverse box alpha) visually seems to appear more natural, though I'm still not sure it's correct. See one screenshot with red drop shadow.

`float outAlpha = clamp(boxAlpha + shadowAlpha, 0.0, 1.0);`

[image: corner zoom 2]
[image: corner zoom 3]
[image: corner zoom 4--red shadow]

**Update 2:**

Okay, I think I solved it now. Slightly further down the wikipedia page is a slight variation on the formula which does not divide by the output alpha. I believe that's my mistake--the first formula assuming a desired output format of straight alpha. Here's my final solution (unless someone chimes in with more input, I will mark as solved in a day or two).

```c
    /* ... */

    float boxAlpha = clamp(0.5 - boxDistance, 0.0, 1.0);
    float shadowAlpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(-blurRadius, blurRadius, boxDistance);

    vec3 boxColor = fragColor * boxAlpha;
    vec3 shadowColor = shadowPaint * shadowAlpha;

    float outAlpha = boxAlpha + (shadowAlpha * (1.0 - boxAlpha));
    vec3 outRgb = boxColor + (shadowColor * (1.0 - boxAlpha));
    outColor = vec4(outRgb * outAlpha, outAlpha);
}
```

[image: corner zoom 5]
[image: corner zoom 6]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appear to have been using the wrong formula. In pre-multiplied alpha, (in hindsight, obviously), you don't divide out the alpha from the color values after compositing.

So the formula to composite object a over object b is:

```
outAlpha = aAlpha + (bAlpha * (1.0 - aAlpha));
outColor = aColor + (bColor * (1.0 - aAlpha));
```

Resulting in the final fragment shader below:

```c
#version 450

layout(location=0) out vec4 outColor;

float sdfRoundedRectangle(vec2 p, vec2 b, float r) {
    vec2 q = abs(p) - b + r;
    return min(max(q.x, q.y), 0.0) + length(max(q, 0.0)) - r;
}

vec2 extent = vec2(600.0, 400.0);
float cornerRadius = 10.0;
float blurRadius = 20.0;
vec3 fragColor = vec3(0.2, 0.5, 0.5);
vec3 shadowPaint = vec3(0.0);

void main()
{
    vec2 center = extent.xy / 2.0;
    vec2 size = (extent.xy / 2.0) - blurRadius;

    float boxDistance = sdfRoundedRectangle(gl_FragCoord.xy - center, size, cornerRadius);

    float boxAlpha = clamp(0.5 - boxDistance, 0.0, 1.0);
    float shadowAlpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(-blurRadius, blurRadius, boxDistance);

    vec3 boxColor = fragColor * boxAlpha;
    vec3 shadowColor = shadowPaint * shadowAlpha;

    float outAlpha = boxAlpha + (shadowAlpha * (1.0 - boxAlpha));
    vec3 outRgb = boxColor + (shadowColor * (1.0 - boxAlpha));
    outColor = vec4(outRgb * outAlpha, outAlpha);
}
```